# Binomial Sample Size with r

Tags: r, sampling

I would like to know if there is any package and how to use it about sample size calculation for binomial distribution. I have to sample fruits in three fields and I have to count the number of defects. I would like to know how many fruits i have to sample for each field taking in account that i would like to see a difference from 1 to 4% of defects.Alpha .05, power .90

Comment: More information is needed!  `?dbinom` or `?pbinom`

Comment: http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/SampleSizeProportions/html/00Index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how the three fields fit into your question, but the `power.prop.test()` function does power calculations for differences in proportions. It looks like you would need about 600 samples per group to tell the difference between a 1% and a 4% incidence with 90% power ...

```
power.prop.test(p1=0.01,p2=0.04,power=0.9,sig.level=0.05)

##     Two-sample comparison of proportions power calculation 

##              n = 567.0721
##             p1 = 0.01
##             p2 = 0.04
##      sig.level = 0.05
##          power = 0.9
##    alternative = two.sided

## NOTE: n is number in *each* group
```